# Setting width of dropdown box in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, parameters

I have created my own script in ArcGIS 10.1 and for one of my parameters I have a drop down list that the user has to select from.  The longest entry in that list is only 6 characters, but the width of the drop down box is the total width of the window.

Is there a way to set the drop down box width to something smaller?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean for a geoprocessing script, then not easily. You can create your [own dialog stylesheet and do some XSLT and Javascript programming](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Changing_tool_dialog_appearance) to customize the controls, but all of that is super painful and not really worth the trouble. I'd recommend just living with the fact that it's as wide as the screen.